# ServletContext initialized two times while deploying

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish-3

When I deploy a web project into Glassfish 3.1,
ServletContextListener->contextInitialized method invoked two times. As far as I know There is only one ServletContext for each web application. ServletContext will be created while deploying the application so ServletContextListener has tobe invoked only one time. 
I think problem is because of Glassfish installed on my local machine. When I have deploy same war file to another machine context initialized only one time as usual so it works properly.

**Here is web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>

<!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


<!-- JSF mapping -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<listener>
    <listener-class>com.mkyong.base.BootStrapper</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**Class file**

```
   import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
   import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

   public class BootStrapper implements ServletContextListener{

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("JavaServerFaces context destroyed.");               
}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("JavaServerFaces context initialized.");
    try {
        throw new Exception();
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

   }
```

**Server.log**

```
[#|2012-12-10T14:50:59.030+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Initializing Mojarra 2.1.3 (FCS b02) for context '/JavaServerFaces'|#]

[#|2012-12-10T14:50:59.114+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2012-12-10T14:50:59.278+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Running on PrimeFaces 3.4.2|#]

[#|2012-12-10T14:50:59.280+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JavaServerFaces context initialized./JavaServerFaces|#]

[#|2012-12-10T14:50:59.280+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.lang.Exception
    at com.mkyong.base.BootStrapper.contextInitialized(BootStrapper.java:17)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.CreateApplicationRefCommand.execute(CreateApplicationRefCommand.java:311)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1045)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:202)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:184)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]

[#|2012-12-10T14:50:59.370+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Initializing Mojarra 2.1.3 (FCS b02) for context '/JavaServerFaces'|#]

[#|2012-12-10T14:50:59.432+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2012-12-10T14:50:59.510+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Running on PrimeFaces 3.4.2|#]

[#|2012-12-10T14:50:59.511+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JavaServerFaces context initialized./JavaServerFaces|#]

[#|2012-12-10T14:50:59.511+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.lang.Exception
    at com.mkyong.base.BootStrapper.contextInitialized(BootStrapper.java:17)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.CreateApplicationRefCommand.execute(CreateApplicationRefCommand.java:311)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1045)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:202)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:184)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]

[#|2012-12-10T14:50:59.516+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0671: Loading application [JavaServerFaces] at [/JavaServerFaces]|#]
```

**Summary of Server.log showing first and second invocation log**

```
    [#|2012-12-10T14:50:59.280+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.lang.Exception
            at com.mkyong.base.BootStrapper.contextInitialized(BootStrapper.java:17)

    [#|2012-12-10T14:50:59.511+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.lang.Exception
    at com.mkyong.base.BootStrapper.contextInitialized(BootStrapper.java:17)
```

Comment: How did you conclude it is invoked twice?

Comment: I have updated the question adding first and second context initializtion log. I have tested the scenario after clearing the server.log file therefore I am sure it is invoked twice.

Comment: Only thing that pops up on google is users that get this behaviour when running several virtual hosts

Comment: edited question, problem should be on Glassfish configuration.

Comment: Couldnt it be that your glassfish installation has several virtual hosts configured?

Comment: You are perfect!!. I have missed that configuration, There are two virtual host defined at a target "server".
I have removed one of them and now context initialization log printed one time.

Comment: Could you move  your comment into answer section :). I will upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is could be due to your application being assigned to several virtual servers in your glassfish configuration.

Read about how virtual servers work in glassfish:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggncs.html#gixku